# Can a cell-complex have no zero cell?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

My question is very simple, but I wasn't able to find an answer in various sources. Cell-complexes are commonly presented using an inductive construction where $n$-cells are attached to $(n-1)$-cells, starting with the data of a collection $X^0$ of $0$-cells.

But sometimes, one will define a $2$-cell for instance, as being a sub-cell complex of something, raising the question: can a cell complex $0$-skeleton be empty? And more generally, can a cell-complex have empty skeletons until a dimension $k$?

It doesn't seem absurd to me that the answer should be yes, but it worries me to never see the case taken into account in the inductive construction.

Comment: The empty space is a CW-complex with no $0$-cells.

Comment: What do you mean by "cell complex"?  Are you using that as a synonym for CW-complex?

Comment: No, I mean a cellular complex, which is basically the same as a CW complex with no closure-finiteness or weak-topology condition (see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244652/what-is-the-difference-between-cw-complex-and-cellular-complex/3046098#3046098) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a nonempty cell complex and let $n$ be minimal such that $X$ has an $n$-cell.  If $n>0$, then this $n$-cell has an attaching map $S^{n-1}\to X^{n-1}$ where $X^{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-skeleton of $X$.  But by minimality of $n$, $X^{n-1}=\emptyset$.  Since $S^{n-1}$ is nonempty, there are no maps $S^{n-1}\to\emptyset$, so this is a contradiction.

So, if $X$ is any nonempty CW-complex, it must have a $0$-cell.  (Of course, the empty space is a CW-complex with no cells at all!)

Comment: thanks, this seems to answer my question accurately! But is it necessary in the definition that the n-cells have attaching maps to the (n-1)-skeleton? Because the 0-cell will not have that for instance.

Comment: In this game, the boundary of the $0$-disc is empty so it attaches perfectly well to the empty $-1$-skeleton :-) @TryingToGetOut

Comment: Yes of course.. Thanks!