# CW-complex of Möbius band without 0-cells

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, mobius-band

So [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_Strip_has_Euler_Characteristic_Zero), and some other sites, claim the Euler-characteristic of the Möbius strip is 0-1+1=0.
Relying on the fact that a Möbius strip has no vertices, i.e. 0-cells.

However I can nowhere find a CW-complex without 0-cells that would result in the Möbius strip. Even more so [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059222/can-a-cell-complex-have-no-zero-cell) directly says that any meaningful CW-complex has at least 1 0-cell.

So I lack the understanding how the Möbius-band has no vertices if in the core of CW-complexes every non-empty space has at least 1 0-cell?

Is vertex=0-cell a simplification, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Every nonempty CW complex has at least one 0-cell, as you say.

Comment: I guess my question isn't really clear to myself either.

Perhaps I should rephrase as:
Clearly there exists no CW-complex without 0-cells. So how come people can claim the Möbius band has 0 vertices?

Comment: Probably the best way to answer that question is to ask the people making the claim. Note also that if they're doing things the "obvious" way — the single 1-cell is the boundary of the Möbius band — then the boundary of the 2-cell will not lie in the 1-skeleton. So there are other problems with their cell structure. Note also that they don't claim that their structure is a CW-decomposition. Maybe they have some other structure in mind?

Comment: I think my understanding of CW-complexes is too little, as I don't see why the boundary of the 2-cell wouldn't correspond to the circle 1-cell surrounding the 2-cell with a loop.

I guess they indeed would be the best to ask, but I'm afraid I won't be able to ever reach them.
Would you know of/hint at a structure which would be more in line with their reasoning and/or are there other ways to define a vertex other than via CW-complexes?

Comment: The region bounded by the circle is not a 2-cell: its interior is not homeomorphic to an open disk. Regarding their reasoning: I have no idea. I think they're just wrong.

Comment: Ah of course: thanks that cleared up a lot. And thank you for your time and effort in commenting.

Comment: @Lay You should now write an answer to yourown question.

Comment: @PaulFrost, ah okay thanks, forget about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the conclusion is that proofwiki and other sources which claim the möbius band has 0 vertices, 1 face and 1 edge, thus calculating $\chi = V - E + F = 0-1+1=0$ for the Euler characteristic, use a more instinctual definition of what a vertex, edge and face are.

A, non-empty, CW-complex has at least 1 0-cell, which intuitively is often seen as a point/vertex, so calculating $\chi$ using CW-complexes will result in a calculation where $\sigma_{0} \geq 1$, where $\sigma_0$is now meant to be the number of 0-cells in the chosen CW-complex; which by the above does not need to correspond with the instinctive idea of a vertex.